# Simultaneous imputation of multiple binary variables in R

Tags: r, missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I have a dataset with multiple correlated binary variables (0/1). Can anyone point me toward a solution for imputing completely random missing values based on information in the other variables?

Below, I provide some code to create a simplified dataset with just 3 correlated binary variables.

```
set.seed(123)
# create correlated random binary (0/1) variables
x1 <- runif(100,0,1)          # N(0,1))
x2 <- x1 * runif(100,0,1)     # N(0,1))
x3 <- x2 * runif(100,0,1)+0.2 # N(0,1))
x1 <- round(x1)
x2 <- round(x2)
x3 <- round(x3)

#introduce random missing (MCAR)
x1[seq(1,100,7)]<-NA
x2[seq(2,100,7)]<-NA
x3[seq(3,100,7)]<-NA
# how can I impute missing values in this dataframe?
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,x3))
cor(df,use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is solution using `mice` package:

```
# just make results reproducible: 

set.seed(123)
# create correlated random binary (0/1) variables
x1 <- runif(100,0,1)          # N(0,1))
x2 <- x1 * runif(100,0,1)     # N(0,1))
x3 <- x2 * runif(100,0,1)+0.2 # N(0,1))
x1 <- round(x1)
x2 <- round(x2)
x3 <- round(x3)
df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,x3))
cor(df1)
          x1        x2        x3
x1 1.0000000 0.4460928 0.3733278
x2 0.4460928 1.0000000 0.3893524
x3 0.3733278 0.3893524 1.0000000

#introduce random missing (MCAR)
x1[seq(1,100,7)]<-NA
x2[seq(2,100,7)]<-NA
x3[seq(3,100,7)]<-NA
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,x3))

# need to create a factor 
df$x1 <- as.factor (df$x1)
df$x2 <- as.factor (df$x2)
df$x3 <- as.factor (df$x3)

require(mice)
imp <- mice(df, seed = 1233, method = "logreg") 
# logistic regression for binary variable 
#Generates multiple imputations for incomplete multivariate data by Gibbs sampling

    complete.df <- complete(imp)
    mdf <- data.matrix(complete.df) # convert to numeric matrix for correlation calculation 
    cor(mdf)
          x1        x2        x3
x1 1.0000000 0.4542568 0.3428222
x2 0.4542568 1.0000000 0.3990563
x3 0.3428222 0.3990563 1.0000000
```

The default value for m (multiple imputation) is 5, probably you would like to increase it to higher (but takes higher computing time).

```
imp <- mice(df, seed = 1233, m = 100,  method = "logreg")
```

You might want to check accuracy of the predictions.

If you need more information consult the package documentation:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/mice.pdf

http://www.jstatsoft.org/v45/i03/paper

Comment: In addition to the nice `mice` package in R, the `aregImpute` function in the `Hmisc` package may be of interest, using predictive mean matching for missing categorical variables.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that "completely random missing values" is MCAR. Besides what has been answered previously, you might want to look at package `cat`, based on work by 
Schafer's [Analysis of Incomplete Multivariable Data](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412040611).